# How to change font size while writing into file?

Tags: python, fonts

I have a string like this
a = 'How to change font size while writing into file'
Here I want to put dots after every two words, but the dot should be in the font size of 1.
How can I achieve this.
I tried with this code

```
with open(r'C:\Users\lguthiko\Desktop\file.txt','w') as f:
    wc = 0
    for i in f:
        w = i.split()
        for word in w:
            wc+=1
            if wc == 2:
                f.write(i.replace(w,'.'+w))
```

But I am not getting how to change the size of dot(.).

Comment: wont `i` just be a single character?

Comment: There i represents an entire line. in every line after every 2 words i am putting dot(.).

Comment: yes my mistake `i` is a line

Comment: 1) plaintext files don't have font sizes, you'd need some sort of rich text (e.g. html) to do this. 
2) I think you're missing a modulo `%` operator, because your code will only put a dot after the second word.

Comment: Apart from that, many things are wrong in your code. For instance, opening a file in write mode will truncate the file, so there won't be anything to read from it. And writing to a file while iterating over its lines is a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

Text files (.txt) do not support different font sizes. It seems like that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: cant we do in word document file even?